# Bold greek letters with fontspec

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math

I am using bold notation for vectors but for some reason I can't display it when I use greek letters:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\usepackage[cal = txupr]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
\mathbf{C}&\equiv\left(a,b,c\right)\\
\mathbf{X_{i}}&\equiv\left(x_{i},y_{i},z_{i}\right)\\
\mathbf{\Delta_{i}}&\equiv \mathbf{C}-\mathbf{X_{i}}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

`\mathbf{C}` and `\mathbf{X_{i}}` work, but `\mathbf{\Delta_{i}}` doesn't. Why is that?

Comment: `\mathbf` works on Latin but not on Greek letters. Since you're using the `unicode-math` package an an OpenType math font, give `\symbf{\Delta}` a try. `\symbf` can used with Greek and Latin letters.

Comment: It worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\symbfit{\gamma}`, etc.  Better yet, define something like

```
\newcommand\vectorsym[1]{\symbfit{#1}
```

This way, if you ever need to change the formatting of vector symbols, again, you can update it in one place, instead of trying to hunt down every vector in all your documents.

An alternative is to load `unicode-math` with the option `mathbf=sym`, if you only ever use `\mathbf` for things like vector symbols.

The reason for this is that `\mathbf` is for bolded words in math mode, and therefore uses the text font.  The default bold text font does not contain Greek letters. If you loaded a Unicode font that supports Greek, with either `\setmainfont` or `\setmathrm`, you would then be able to write Greek words such as `\alpha \mathbf{ και } \beta`.  (Although something like `\textnormal{\bfseries ...}` also works and might be less ambiguous.)

Comment: Is \symbfit different from \symbf?

Comment: @Rodrigo `\symbfit` is bold italic. `\symbf` might be italic or upright, depending on your `math-style`.

Comment: @Rodrigo In ISO style, `\symbfit` is correct, but many mathematicians instead use bold upright for either capital Greek letters or all vectors.